# How to implement MediaStyle notifications to support Android Oreo?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

In my android app that I am working on, I have implemented MediaPlayer service class (PlayService.java) which will play live radio audio stream from a remote source. When a service runs in the foreground, it displays a notification  with play/pause media transport control so that the user can handle media player actions from there also. I am successful in doing all so and I have tested my application on currently used versions of android (i.e. Jellybean, Kitkat, Lollipop, Marshmallow and Nougat). The app with notification works fine as desired but my app doesn't show notification in Android version 8.0(Oreo). I have research alot and tried multiple links like https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-mediastyle-notifications-to-support-android-o-29c7edeca9b7 but couldn't find any proper solution.

My working code for MediaPlayer Service class is:

```
public class PlayService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener,MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener,AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener  {

    private AudioManager audioManager;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private String sentAudioLink="";

    //Used to pause/resume MediaPlayer
    private int resumePosition;

    //Handle notification in system tray
    private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private int notification_id;
    private RemoteViews remoteViews;

    public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.ACTION_PLAY";
    public static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "com.example.ACTION_PAUSE";
    public static final String ACTION_STOP = "com.example.ACTION_STOP";

    //MediaSession
    private MediaSessionManager mediaSessionManager;
    private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;
    private MediaControllerCompat.TransportControls transportControls;

    //AudioPlayer notification ID
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            sentAudioLink = intent.getExtras().getString("sentAudioLink");
        }

        mediaPlayer.reset();
        //setup the media player data source using the strAudioLink value
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(sentAudioLink);
                //prepare media player
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e("workingerror1", e.toString());
                stopSelf();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.e("workingerror2", e.toString());
                stopSelf();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("workingerror3", e.toString());
                stopSelf();
            }
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PLAYING);
        }
        //Handle Intent action from MediaSession.TransportControls
        handleIncomingActions(intent);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            removeNotification();
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer=null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        stopMedia();
        stopSelf();
        buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED);
    }

    public void stopMedia() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        playMedia();
    }

    public void playMedia() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && sentAudioLink!="") {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    private void buildNotification(PlaybackStatus playbackStatus) {

        int notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;//needs to be initialized
        PendingIntent play_pauseAction = null;

        //PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //Build a new notification according to the current state of the MediaPlayer
        if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PLAYING) {
            notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;
            //create the pause action
            play_pauseAction = playbackAction(1);
        } else if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PAUSED) {
            notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;
            //create the play action
            play_pauseAction = playbackAction(0);
        }

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.uow_logo); //replace with your own image

        // Create a new Notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setShowWhen(false)
                // Set the Notification style
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        // Show our playback controls in the compact notification view.
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0))
                // Set the Notification color
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                // Set the large and small icons
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.uow_logo)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                // Set Notification content information
                .setContentText("FM Radia")
                .setContentTitle("title abc")
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(true)
                // Add playback actions
                .addAction(notificationAction, "pause", play_pauseAction);


        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    private void removeNotification() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }

    private PendingIntent playbackAction(int actionNumber) {
        Intent playbackAction = new Intent(this, PlayService.class);
        switch (actionNumber) {
            case 0:
                // Play
                playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PLAY);
                return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
            case 1:
                // Pause
                playbackAction.setAction(ACTION_PAUSE);
                return PendingIntent.getService(this, actionNumber, playbackAction, 0);
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void handleIncomingActions(Intent playbackAction)
    {
        if (playbackAction == null || playbackAction.getAction() == null) return;

        String actionString = playbackAction.getAction();
        Log.e("actionString",actionString);
        if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PLAY))
        {
            //Play the music
        }
        else (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_PAUSE))
        {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
            buildNotification(PlaybackStatus.PAUSED);
            stopSelf();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `NotificationCompat.Builder(Context)` was deprecated in api 26. From api 26 you must pass `channelId` in class constructor.

Comment: i will try and let you know.